# UIImageView initWithCoder - unrecognized selector sent to instance... iOS 5 beta SDK

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiactivityindicatorview, ios5, xcode4.2

I'm sorry if it has already been asked, but here comes the problem:

I've recently updated my SDK to **iOS 5 beta**. My app builds and runs perfectly fine on the new simulator, but when I try to change the Deployment Target to the older iOS (**4.3**), the app crashes instantly when it tries to use **UIActivityIndicatorView** control (both simulator and device). I'm using the **UIActivityIndicatorView** in a really simple loading view consisting only of a **View** and **UIActivityIndicatorView**.

When I remove **UIActivityIndicatorView** control from that view, the view works fine, *BUT* the app crashes while loading other views (with activity indicators and images). So, the long story short: app works fine in the iOS 5 environment, but images and activity indicators crash it while running it on older iOS versions. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**:

I'm adding some code just to show you guys how I'm using the view. It's really not much and the **LoadingViewController** itself has absolutely no custom code (all controls are in the nib).

```
if(!self.loadingScreen){
    self.loadingScreen = [[LoadingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoadingViewController" bundle:nil];
}
[self.view addSubview:loadingScreen.view];
```

The exception message doesn't actually say much more, but here you go:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x017bd5a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01911313 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x017bf0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0172e966 ___forwarding___ + 966
4   CoreFoundation                      0x0172e522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
5   UIKit                               0x00f8e9fd UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592
6   UIKit                               0x00f8f6ac -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398
7   UIKit                               0x00d75db0 -[UIImageView initWithCoder:] + 97
```

Comment: could you post some code and the exact crash message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following smith324's advice I started to browse Apple dev forums to find out if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a bug in the SDK. It turns out, that there's a nasty bug in the latest release crashing UIImages, UIActivityIndicators etc. just like in my case. Good news is, **there actually is a workaround** and you can find it here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/507796#507796

Thanks everyone for your help!

EDIT:

If you can't access the link, this is the suggested answer:

```
@implementation UIImage (initWithCoder)

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
     return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and just found a solution.
My UIActivityIndicator was added into a xib file. I have removed it from the xib and have created it by code (activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:...).

All is ok now, it works !

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: you had a very good idea, your solutions works, the app does not crash, but I'm afraid it is far from what I'm looking for - I would have to redesign all views to apply that change. I've seen few tweets about this error but no answers. I'm getting more and more convinced that this is a problem with the SDK.

Comment: Not to be that guy, but the Beta SDK is under NDA. Which means this should be on Apple's developer forums.

Answer (score 1):

I can't open URL https://devforums.apple.com/message/507796#507796.... but I think you can make a category for UIImage class, like this:

```
@implementation UIImage (Coder)

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
     return nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is exactly how they did it. I believe it's fixed in the latest version of iOS though.

Comment: So do I :) Honestly, I'm upset by latest xCode. It is too slow as for me.

Comment: True, it can drive me mad sometimes. But after all, it's worth it when you see your app running :)

Comment: :) yep. In any case, I'm going to buy powerfull iMac because I'm going crazy while working on Mac Book Pro, especially in Summer.