# Help to solve Apple's crash-reports logs

Tags: crash-reports, ipad-2

my app was rejected for a crash that i didn't notice on the simulator. 
Here are the logs, (already imported on XCode > Organizer ) can someone help me with this?

```
Incident Identifier: 88AD655D-3540-419C-A883-EFCEEB8CFE16
CrashReporter Key:   6b6d313765323bdd8ad35c9b99c487d423fd70ab
Hardware Model:      iPad2,2
Process:         MyApp [7983]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/F9B518BA-1F72-449C-B584-45E77ECB9CB8/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-09-21 17:14:13.004 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.5 (8L1)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361eda1c 0x361dc000 + 72220
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322df3b4 0x322ac000 + 209844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322d7bf8 0x322ac000 + 179192
3   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32729a64 0x326e5000 + 281188
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x336b606c 0x336b0000 + 24684
5   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32727e36 0x326e5000 + 273974
6   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32727e8a 0x326e5000 + 274058
7   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x32727f5a 0x326e5000 + 274266
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x336b4c84 0x336b0000 + 19588
9   CoreFoundation                  0x35b4848a +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 62
10  CoreFoundation                  0x35b484c4 +[NSException raise:format:] + 28
11  UIKit                           0x32a51a4c -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1104
12  UIKit                           0x32a52e02 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 86
13  UIKit                           0x329cc5e2 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 30
14  UIKit                           0x32999f9e -[UIViewController loadView] + 74
15  UIKit                           0x328e1b1e -[UITableViewController loadView] + 46
16  UIKit                           0x3287eeb8 -[UIViewController view] + 24
17  UIKit                           0x3288d5e8 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 16
18  UIKit                           0x3288d458 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 24
19  UIKit                           0x3288d356 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 18
20  UIKit                           0x3288ce2e -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 374
21  UIKit                           0x3288cc3c -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 176
22  UIKit                           0x3288cb80 -[UINavigationController viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 8
23  UIKit                           0x3288cb1c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 132
24  UIKit                           0x3284d5f4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 20
25  CoreFoundation                  0x35ab5efc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
26  QuartzCore                      0x309ffbae -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 114
27  QuartzCore                      0x309ff966 CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 178
28  QuartzCore                      0x30a051be CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 206
29  QuartzCore                      0x30a04fd0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 184
30  QuartzCore                      0x309fe04e CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 50
31  CoreFoundation                  0x35b1fa2e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 10
32  CoreFoundation                  0x35b2145e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 406
33  CoreFoundation                  0x35b22754 __CFRunLoopRun + 848
34  CoreFoundation                  0x35ab2ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
35  CoreFoundation                  0x35ab2dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
36  GraphicsServices                0x308a7418 GSEventRunModal + 108
37  GraphicsServices                0x308a74c4 GSEventRun + 56
38  UIKit                           0x32876d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
39  UIKit                           0x32874800 UIApplicationMain + 664
40  MyApp               0x00002622 0x1000 + 5666
41  MyApp               0x000025ec 0x1000 + 5612

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361ee3ec 0x361dc000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322e06d8 0x322ac000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322e0bbc 0x322ac000 + 215996

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361eefbc 0x361dc000 + 77756
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31d33ed4 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 744
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x31d34f3a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 70
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x31d344ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 228
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322e058a 0x322ac000 + 214410
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322e0bbc 0x322ac000 + 215996

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361ee3ec 0x361dc000 + 74732
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322e06d8 0x322ac000 + 214744
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322e0bbc 0x322ac000 + 215996

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361ebc00 0x361dc000 + 64512
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x361eb758 0x361dc000 + 63320
2   CoreFoundation                  0x35b202b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x35b22562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x35ab2ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x35ab2dc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x35d8327e _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322df30a 0x322ac000 + 209674
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x322e0bb4 0x322ac000 + 215988

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x3f42b48c    r5: 0x00000006      r6: 0x0054f56c      r7: 0x2fdfd3e8
    r8: 0x3f1b2964    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x00537f10     r11: 0x368d9d97
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fdfd3dc      lr: 0x322df3bb      pc: 0x361eda1c
  cpsr: 0x000f0010
```

Apple said

> We found that your app crashed on iPad 2 running iOS 4.3.5, which is
>   not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Specifically, we noticed that your app crashes when selecting the
>   "Favorites" tab.

But to me, Favorites Tab works fine (even if i don't have an iPad, i work through the simulator)

Thanks

Comment: It looks like there is a problem loading your nib, have you checked the paths of any images that nib references?

Comment: You mean the NIB of "Favorites" tab?

Comment: Right, since that appears to be what's triggering the crash.

Comment: It's really weird, 'cause on the simulator it works really good. It shows up the nib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be the same problem with the SDK bug in 4.3.5 related to the method loadNibNamed.

See the accepted answer to this question for temporary resolution until Apple release a fix: [UIImageView initWithCoder - unrecognized selector sent to instance... iOS 5 beta SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023430/uiimageview-initwithcoder-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-ios-5-beta)

The question relates to iOS 5 beta. However, I believe it is the same ongoing problem.

Comment: Thanks,i'll take a look! (even if i'm using XCode 4.1, 'cause of the bugs in the beta versions)

Comment: yeah I think that the same method appearing in these crashes and in the various posts and logs is too hard to ignore. So, it's definitely worth a try at this solution.